# Android java.lang.NullPointerException using HostTab

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm using `Android 2.1` and `HostTab` activity, but when I compile get crash in my app
with the error `"java.lang.NullPointerException"`. I'm not sure, but I guess `HostTab` have a problem with `Android 2.1` Pls need help, anyone can check out my code? TY

My Log is

```
    08-17 19:54:08.025: D/ddm-heap(215): Got feature list request
    08-17 19:54:08.035: D/AndroidRuntime(215): Shutting down VM
    08-17 19:54:08.035: W/dalvikvm(215): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{utec.academico/utec.academico.Academico}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at utec.academico.Academico.onCreate(Academico.java:28)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
    08-17 19:54:08.035: E/AndroidRuntime(215):  ... 11 more
    08-17 19:54:08.055: I/dalvikvm(215): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    08-17 19:54:08.055: E/dalvikvm(215): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
    08-17 19:54:09.306: I/Process(215): Sending signal. PID: 215 SIG: 9
```

My manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="utec.academico"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Academico">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Horario"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Asistencia"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Notas"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetalleNotas"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Record"></activity>
</application>
```

My principal Hosttab class

```
public class Academico extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.academico);

    TabHost tabHost=getTabHost(); //Creamos el tabhost de la actividad
    tabHost.setup();      

    TabHost.TabSpec spec;         //Creamos el recurso para la propiedad de la pestaña
    Intent intent;                //intent para abrir la pestaña 
    Resources res= getResources();//Obtenemos los recursos

    //Establecemos el recurso de color para todos los tabs
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    //Se crea el  intent para abrir la actividad, configuramos y cargamos el tab en el contenedor tabhost
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Horario.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Horario").setContent(intent).setIndicator("Horario",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.horario));  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Notas.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Notas").setContent(intent).setIndicator("  Notas  ");  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Asistencia.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Asistencia").setContent(intent).setIndicator("Asistencia",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.asistencia));  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Record.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Record").setContent(intent).setIndicator("  Record Académico  ");  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);        
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.academico, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Then my HostTab xml is

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout 
           android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>   
    <TabWidget
           android:id="@android:id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0"
           android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp">
    </TabWidget>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you mark/notate which is line 28?

Comment: Learning how to read the logcat is very helpful. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException ... at utec.academico.Academico.onCreate(Academico.java:28)` These are the important lines from your logcat. They tell us that the NPE was thrown on line 28 in Academico, specifically in onCreate(). Start here with the debugger find out where the null value is. (I agree with nandeesh `getChild(0)` probably returns null and `null.setBackgroundColor()` causes an NPE.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is at

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Move this to the end of Oncreate